# Cookie not printing once it is created in the same page

Tags: php, cookies

I created the Cookie Named "test" with the value "one" with following Code in the page `index.php`

```
 <?php
 setcookie('test','one');
 echo $_COOKIE['test'];
 ?>
```

Once i open the page index.php the Cookie is not printed and once i refresh the page, the cookie is printed (printed because of cookie already created)

My Question is the cookie is created when i run the page index.php first time itself and once i print the cookie it should be printed, then

> what is the reason the cookie Not getting print in the first run
>   itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Question is the cookie is created when i run the page index.php
> first time itself and once i print the cookie it should be printed,
> then

### Yes the cookie is created when you run the `index.php` the first time.

> what is the reason the cookie Not getting print in the first run
> itself ?

Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the `$_COOKIE` or `$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS` arrays.

[`Source`](https://www.php.net/set_cookie)

Browse down the link to see the common pitfalls..

### Common Pitfalls:

- Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling `print_r($_COOKIE);`.
- Cookies must be deleted with the same parameters as they were set with. If the value argument is an empty string, or FALSE, and all other arguments match a previous call to setcookie, then the cookie with the specified name will be deleted from the remote client. This is internally achieved by setting value to 'deleted' and expiration time to one year in past.
- Because setting a cookie with a value of FALSE will try to delete the cookie, you should not use boolean values. Instead, use 0 for FALSE and 1 for TRUE.
- Cookies names can be set as array names and will be available to your PHP scripts as arrays but separate cookies are stored on the user's system. Consider `explode()` to set one cookie with multiple names and values. It is not recommended to use `serialize()` for this purpose, because it can result in security holes.

Comment: But why it is not getting printed while i run the page for first time. {I mean after clearing all the cookies in the browser}

Comment: @Stackerman, You definitely can't display that. That is the first point of the **pitfalls** mentioned in the PHP Document.

Comment: Downvoter please reason so I can refine the answer.

Comment: The source you provided cleared my problem. [link] http://in3.php.net/set_cookie

Comment: Thanks @Stackerman, but I dont know why this answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie('test','one');
```

will add the below the the http header to the response, which is used to let the browser set the cookie.

```
Set-Cookie: test=one ...
```

---

If the cookie is set in the browser side, then the next time, when you access the page, the request header will have the below:

```
Cookie: name=value; ...
```

This data is used to set the super global `$_COOKIE`, so only from the second time you will see the value.

#### The first time you only tell the browser to set the cookie, at the time, there is no cookie data in the request header, so you will not see the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in ur question itself.
This line:
setcookie('test','one')--> When you run the index.php, the cookie is sent by the PHP script and **SET** in your browser so, your PHP script will not be able to **READ** the value as it just SETS your cookie, the first time it runs.

So, only after the cookie is **SET**, when you run the second time,[Since the cookie contains value this time] it is **READ** and printed by the PHP Script 
Hope that clear the things

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is Created the Cookie and printing it in the same page, The Cookies could not be printed in the same page itself because it the user to load the next page. You can try printing the cookie in the next page.

```
  <?php
  echo $_COOKIE['test'];
  ?>
```

And you can store the Cookie by

```
$a=$_COOKIE['test'];
```

The purpose of storing it in the variable $a is the value of the cookie will be remain same even the cookie is unset, but the value of $a should not be changed.